How to implement Previous and Next buttons in my Embla Carousel?
I have implemented an Embla Carousel inside my (Work in progress) website home page. For the past hour or so I have been trying to implement buttons to control the carousel one slide at a time. When trying to put them in as follows:
<Button className="w-[20%] h-[20%] ">
   <ArrowCircleRight className="w-full h-full text-white" /> 
</Button>

The end result looks is the following: The button is placed inside the carousel container along with the slides
My full code is the following:
<html lang="en" className="h-full">
  <head>
    <title>[My website]</title>
  </head>
  <body
    className={`${lusitana.className} antialiased min-h-screen flex flex-col`}
  >
    <BackgroundImage />
    <main className="flex-grow">
      <div className="flex items-center w-full h-[51dvh] justify-center">
        <div className="relative w-[80%] h-full hidden md:flex">
          <div className="h-full w-full overflow-hidden" ref={emblaRef}> <-- Carousel code starts here
            <div className="h-full flex items-center gap-4"> <-- Container (as named in carousel docs)
              <div className="embla__viewport h-full"> <-- Viewport is here 
                <div className="flex-shrink-0 min-w-[300px] h-full max-w-xs sm:max-w-sm md:max-w-md lg:max-w-lg xl:max-w-xl bg-white rounded-md overflow-hidden flex flex-col p-2"> <-- Individual slide code starts here
                  <div className="w-full flex-grow relative">
                    <Image
                      src="https://placehold.co/400x500"
                      alt="Garment Image"
                      layout="fill"
                      objectFit="cover"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <hr className="m-2" />
                  <div className="flex flex-col">
                    <Link href={"#"}>
                      <div className="pb-3 px-3">
                        <p className="text-lg sm:text-xl md:text-2xl font-semibold truncate">
                          Garment Title
                        </p>
                        <p className="text-sm sm:text-md text-gray-400 line-clamp-2">
                          Garment Description
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="p-3 space-y-2">
                      <Button className="w-full outline outline-1 rounded-md h-8 hover:bg-gray-100 outline-gray-700 text-gray-700">
                        View
                      </Button>
                      <Button className="w-full outline outline-1 rounded-md h-8 bg-gray-700 text-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-800">
                        Request Trade
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <Button className="w-[20%] h-[20%] ">
                <ArrowLeftCircleIcon className="w-full h-full text-white" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>

(Some irrelevant code was excluded from the above code block)
I have so far tried to insert the button outside of the container (while still remaining within the Parent Component) however no location I have tried so far seems to be getting it out of the carousel and beside it.
